# Open Mail.app on IPhone from webpage that's INSIDE an app

Tags: iphone, hyperlink, mailto, tel

our app loads profile pages from our website INSIDE the app. They have been optimized for iPhone css, but they are still an html page. Our mailto link isnt working as expected.
When clicked, nothing happens. However, when clicked and held (tap and hold), the menu slides up with "new message", "create new contact", "copy", etc.

**How should this be formatted to get the Mail.app to automatically launch?**

```
<a class="action_bubble" target="_blank" rel="external" href="mailto:bob@bob.com">Send Email</a>
```

The "call" link works as expected.

```
<a class="action_bubble" href="tel:1234567890">Call</a>
```

So, not sure what to do with this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [project on GitHub](https://github.com/sburlot/browserviewcontroller) that addresses your issue. Basically, when you use a UIWebView controller, you need to decide how to manage the links using the delegate handler for UIWebView. In Interface Builder you can have it automatically recognize phone numbers which is probably why your phone numbers work and it will recognize `http` links as default behavior. However, `mailto` and some of the other special `href` options will need to be handled manually.

Answer (score 1):

make sure "Detection" property is set for your UIWebView like "Phone","Address". you can set it from your IB.

or from code

self.webView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;

Comment: The items (address, events , links) were not checked, so I checked them, then rebuilt and tested on the device with no change. The phone links work, the others do not. Well, not as expected anyway, the map link pulls up the map inside the app, not in the map app and the email will slide up a panel IF you hold the button down long enough...

Answer (score 0):

Could it be, that you have just tried within the simulator? The simulator does not have a mail app, so it couldn't be opened. Try on a device. I think your code actually works.

I've just tested on a device: your code works.

Comment: Another team member is handling the development of the app, i was just making the web page that it calls. Looks like I am going to gt a dev license and start making iPhone apps...

Comment: Your code is working: it's the simulator. Test on a device and it'll work.

Comment: I wasn't on the simulator, I was in the app on my phone... but glad to know it's not MY code.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party but I've found out the following:

1. iOS has some weird ways to deal with web content
2. DON'T encapsulate your email address within an A tag, just put it there as plain text
3. Make sure that in your storyboard (if using one) the webView has the Addresses property checked and you're done ... same goes for phone numbers